# mysql_real_escape_string(); problems

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I seem to be having a small problem with mysql_real_escape_string();

Its not giving me a return value, for example i am using it like this:

```
$a = mysql_real_escape_string($tableName);
```

but $a is blank.

I have run several tests like so:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE ".$tableName." AS (SELECT * FROM availability WHERE 1=2)";

echo "query: " . $query;

echo "tableName: " . $a;
```

and the output is as follows:

```
query: CREATE TABLE gRLEFCnOauUlJAekIEq5 AS (SELECT * FROM availability WHERE 1=2)tableName:
```

As you can see the query is as expected, but the the $a shows nothing.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I hope you're not using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking...............

Comment: Please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are obsolete, insecure and deprecated. It is recommended to switch to `mysqli_xx()` functions or PDO as soon as possible.

Comment: For future users seeing your questions. If you know this, great! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` requires an active connection to the database. You will need to connect to the database with `mysql_connect()` for it to work.

However, it would be better to switch to PDO or MySQLi and use a prepared statement because:

1. The `mysql_*` library is deprecated.
2. A prepared statement is better than escaping.

Answer (score 3):

In order for `mysql_real_escape_string` to work, you **must** have an active database connection. If you cannot have a database connection, then use `mysql_escape_string` instead.

Side note: neither one of these is ideal, as the mysql extension is deprecated. You should move towards PDO or mysqli.

Comment: impressive to have two virtually identical (but clearly separately written answers) posted within a second of each other.